# Filtering list in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list

```
  A <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
  B <- c("a" ,"b", "c" ,"d","b" ,"f" ,"g" ,"a" ,"b" ,"a")
  C <- c(25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 10, 15)
  mylist <- list(A,B,C)
  mylist  
  [[1]]
  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

  [[2]]
  [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "b" "f" "g" "a" "b" "a" 

  [[3]]
  [1] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 10 15
```

I would like to select all components A,B,C of the list where second component B has value "a" or "b" .

Sample output

```
  mylist  
  [[1]]
  [1]  1  2  6  8  9 10

  [[2]]
  [1] "a" "b" "b" "a" "b" "a" 

  [[3]]
  [1] 25 26 29 32 10 15
```

How can I do that? Note that each component have same length.

Comment: If all components have same length, it would be easier to use a `data.frame` !!!

Comment: You are changing the question each time.  You should provide an example that mimics the original dataset rather than keep changing what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To stay with a `list`, why not simply:

```
lapply(mylist, `[`, is.element(B, letters[1:2]))
#[[1]]
#[1]  1  2  5  8  9 10

#[[2]]
#[1] "a" "b" "b" "a" "b" "a"

#[[3]]
#[1] 25 26 29 32 10 15
```

Comment: What if I don't know the position? Actually this is a sample data. I have around thousand elements. I tried using `lapply` for each values "a" and "b" and combined the list. But I want to know how to filter the list for 5 variables. Is there any method other than creating 5 lists and combining them?

Comment: what do you mean by "what if I do not know the position" ? There is ... no position in the code I produced (except the index `1:2` for `letters`)

Comment: I mean what if I don't know the positions of "a" and "b".

Comment: No problem, note that `is.element` and `%in%` do the same thing, but I prefer the first one, it's more elegant writting (very subjective)

Answer (score 3):

I would go with a data.frame or data.table for this use case:

Using your original list (with a 10 added to A to have the same number of entries as B and C):

```
>df <- data.frame(A=mylist[[1]],B=mylist[[2]],C=mylist[[3]],stringsAsFactors=F)
> df[df$B %in% c("a","b"),]
    A B  C
1   1 a 25
2   2 b 26
5   5 b 29
8   8 a 32
9   9 b 10
10 10 a 15
```

This will subset the data.frame by where B values are  a or b. If you build your list at first, you may avoid the list step and build the data.frame directly.

If you really want a list at end:

```
> as.list(df[df$B %in% c("a","b"),])
$A
[1]  1  2  5  8  9 10

$B
[1] "a" "b" "b" "a" "b" "a"

$C
[1] 25 26 29 32 10 15
```

If you wish to avoid the named entries, use `unname`: `as.list(unname(df[..]))`

Comment: just do `df = setNames(data.frame(mylist), LETTERS[1:3])` instead of this ugly indexing ;)

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Indeed, but as I'm unsure OP's is not building the list before, I wished to show he can do `data.frame(A=A,B=B,C=C)` from the original vectors (But I may have been more explicit on this)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution.

First, I create mylist :

> mylist <- list(1:10, letters[1:10], 25:15)

Then I create a function which returns TRUE if the condition is TRUE and FALSE otherwise

```
> filt <- function(x) {
+   x[2] %in% c("a", "b")
+ }
>
```

Then I use `sapply` to apply the function to `mylist` and I select only the components I need :

```
> mylist[sapply(mylist, filt) == TRUE]
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```